# Why is my buffer not concatenating?

Tags: c, debugging, io, environment-variables

If no args to main then my program should do `printenv | sort | less` and I've achieved that functionality. If main has arguments then the program should do `printenv | grep <parameter list> | sort | less` and my problem is that debugging is not working. I can try statement `printf` in my code and it doesn't do anything. Why? And why is the latter part of my requirement not working? What is wrong with the program?

The expected output is `printenv | grep <parameter list> | sort | less`. For example I would like to query the environment variables so that executing `a.out JOBS COMPIZ UPSTART` should be doing the same as a `printenv | grep -e 'JOBS\|COMPIZ\|UPSTART' | sort | less`.

Instead I get unexpected output when trying to fork a chain of commands.

```
#include <sys/types.h> /* definierar bland annat typen pid_t */
#include <errno.h> /* definierar felkontrollvariabeln errno */
#include <stdio.h> /* definierar stderr, dit felmeddelanden skrivs */
#include <stdlib.h> /* definierar bland annat exit() */
#include <unistd.h> /* definierar bland annat fork() */

struct command
{
    const char **argv;
};

int
spawn_proc (int in, int out, struct command *cmd)
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork ()) == 0)
    {
        if (in != 0)
        {
            dup2 (in, 0);
            close (in);
        }

        if (out != 1)
        {
            dup2 (out, 1);
            close (out);
        }

        return execvp (cmd->argv [0], (char * const *)cmd->argv);
    }

    return pid;
}

int
fork_pipes (int n, struct command *cmd)
{
    int i;
    pid_t pid;
    int in, fd [2];

    /* The first process should get its input from the original file descriptor 0.  */
    in = 0;

    /* Note the loop bound, we spawn here all, but the last stage of the pipeline.  */
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        pipe (fd);

        /* f [1] is the write end of the pipe, we carry `in` from the prev iteration.  */
        spawn_proc (in, fd [1], cmd + i);

        /* No need for the write and of the pipe, the child will write here.  */
        close (fd [1]);

        /* Keep the read end of the pipe, the next child will read from there.  */
        in = fd [0];
    }

    /* Last stage of the pipeline - set stdin be the read end of the previous pipe
       and output to the original file descriptor 1. */
    if (in != 0)
        dup2 (in, 0);

    /* Execute the last stage with the current process. */
    return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);
}

int
main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("in main...");
    int i;

    if (argc == 1) {
        const char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
        const char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
        const char *less[] = { "less", 0 };

        struct command cmd [] = { {printenv}, {sort}, {less} };
        return fork_pipes (3, cmd);
    }
    if (argc > 1) {
        char *tmp = argv[1];
        for( i=1; i<argc-1; i++)
        {
            sprintf(tmp, "%s%s%s", tmp, "|", argv[i]);
        }
        const char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
        const char *grep[] = { "grep", "-E", tmp, NULL};
        const char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
        const char *less[] = { "less", 0 };

        struct command cmd [] = { {printenv}, {grep}, {sort}, {less} };
        return fork_pipes (4, cmd);
    }




}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. "Why is my program not working?" has absolutely no indication of what question you're asking or what problem you're experiencing. Question titles should contain information that will be useful to future readers of this site when they see it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are writing to a read-only memory segment by writing to `argv[1]` (due to the `tmp = argv[1]` statement). It is further aggravated by the fact that you are more than likely writing beyond the size of `argv[1]`. Instead you should concatenate the string to a new writable buffer of sufficient size.

To concatenate the string into the `tmp` variable you can use code similar to the following:

```
    // Compute required buffer length
    int len = 1; // adds 1 to the length to account for the \0 terminating char
    for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
      len += strlen(argv[i]) + 2; // +2 accounts for length of "\\|"
    }

    // Allocate buffer
    tmp = (char*) malloc(len);
    tmp[0] = '\0';
    // Concatenate argument into buffer
    int pos = 0;
    for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
      pos += sprintf(tmp+pos, "%s%s", (i==1?"":"|"), argv[i]);
    }

    printf("tmp:%s", tmp);
    fflush(stdout); // force string to be printed

    ...
    free(tmp);
```

As far as why the output does not appear, it is most likely due to the fact that `printf` is line buffered. In other words, it typically won't be printed until an end-of-line (`\n`) has to be printed or a `fflush` explicitly forces the buffer to be printed to the console.

*Note*: don't forget to `free()` the variable `tmp` once you are done with it.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz I've tweaked the generated string to be more in line with what seems to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. Now I only need to know how to send to arguments verbatim to grep since my old call is no longer working. I suppose I should use some other instruction now that we no longer keep the `|`.

Comment: what kind of arguments where you intending to pass to grep? Btw you would need to generate an array of string if you want the arguments to be passed as separated arguments as you invoke grep with `execvp` (like you did for `grep[] = { "grep", "-E", tmp, NULL};`)

Comment: The requirement is to enable querying the environement variables e.g. `a.out JOBS COMPIZ UPSTART` should be doing the same as a `printenv | grep -e 'JOBS\|COMPIZ\|UPSTART' | sort | less` so I must allow for passing arguments like that.

Comment: ah! '\\|' is quite different from a '|' separator.

Comment: @SleuthEye the first argument shouldn't be preceded by `"\\|"` else you would make up a command line like `grep -e '\|JOBS[...]'`

Comment: Thing is when using the program I must allow for greping using the arguments and I found it must be `const char *grep[] = { "grep", "-E", "JOB|COMPIZ|UPSTART", NULL};` without the backslash but I don't know how to buildup the query.